# pandas Apply function not works on Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I would like to retrieve name from the Pnadas dataframe using regex, but pandas Apply function is not working on DataFrame object. It worked fine on pandas series object. Please explain for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
doc = pd.DataFrame(['William Hartnell (1963-66)',
'Patrick Troughton (1966-69)',
'Jon Pertwee (1970 74)',
'Tom Baker (1974-81)',
'Peter Davison (1982-84)'])

p = re.compile('\w+\s+\w+')

def get_name(s):
    return p.match(s).group()

nam = docs.apply(get_name) # gives me an error

nam = doc[0].apply(get_name) # works fine
```

Why my function cannot be applied to dataframe? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

when you use the apply function it iterates all values in the specified zone.

This code passes the entire dataframe row into your function, which p.match cannot use.

```
doc.apply(get_name) #Note that you should also put axis=1
```

This code, however, passes only the column with the name in it, and therefore p.match can use it successfully.

```
doc[0].apply(get_name)
```